# How to create a Home folder in ErpNext File Doctype after deleting it?

Tags: debugging, erpnext, frappe

After I run frappe.db.delete(“File”) I have now this error every time I uploaded a file and I can’t create a Home folder. Any idea how to solve this? I also want to know how to create a Home folder on ERPNext.

[Folder Home did not found image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvijL.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I have right now is to insert a Home on tabFile table.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).